# Grease pencil unusably slow

Tags: 3d-view, grease-pencil, performance

I'm trying to use grease pencil to do some animated screencasting-sort-of videos. I've used it before to do quick animations and noticed that even with a dozen or so vertices the performance drops. At the time I assumed it was due to me using some beta version of Blender. However now I've reset all blender settings, erased all the caches and configs and installed the stable version (Arch Linux official repos, Blender 2.91.0) and even tried the zip files from the blender website and I can't figure out the problem.

I have more than enough RAM (16 GB) and blender uses barely 5% when working on the screenshotted file. The CPU isn't loaded either (8% from blender and at about 15% total). I have a Ryzen 3600x with an RX480 GPU with 8GB VRAM). Not a supercomputer but it shouldn't have trouble working with a bit of grease pencil.

Now, to describe the problem: as time goes on, blender gets slower and slower even with small grease pencil files. With the file I'm trying to work with it's downright unusable right from the start. It works fine as long as the GPencil object is not selected but once it is... the viewport performance drops to 1.2 fps and it becomes unusable. Am I missing something stupid simple? Also it would seem that in edit mode there is no problem.

[image]
As you can see, the file isn't big, barely a couple hundred vertices (I actually don't know how to check the number, if anyone has a suggestion I would love to be able to do that.

Apologies for the rant-like post. If you need any information such as logs or whatnot, I am at your disposal.

Best regards

EDIT: My 5-year old laptop has no issues with Grease Pencil. But the fact that I cleansed everything blender and reinstalled it many times including using archived files from the official website and building it myself... makes me think it's not really a problem with my PC, especially since it only happens in object mode with Grease Pencil selected.

EDIT_2: [Quick video demo](https://youtu.be/oc19GYSBpUM)

Comment: Have you tried disabling the build modifier in the viewport?

Comment: Yes, it makes no difference at all

Comment: Maybe it would work in 2.83 LTS.

Comment: It does not. Also I checked that on a laptop and it has no issues with the same blender executable. So it's something specific to my computer. Which is extremely weird since I purged ~/.config/blender and reinstalled it many times, used standalone binaries, built it myself etc... The fact that it slows down only in object mode with the GPencil selected nonetheless makes me think it's a blender problem

Comment: RX480 GPU is the likely suspect. What kind of GPU is the other computer using?

Comment: The laptop is a Dell XPS 13.The GPU inside it is an intel 620.
The RX480 is not a high end GPU by any means but it's miles ahead of an old 620 (and it's not an iGPU).

Comment: AMD is the problem, not the newness of the GPU. Try downgrading the drivers.

Comment: That's fairly complicated to do and will probably result in a broken system. Rolling release distributions do not work nicely with downgrades. I will rather try to boot on a live USB and test various scenarios starting with checking if it works out of the box